# How to select specific rows to load into an Excel Workbook from another at run-time

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have to .xlsx files. One has data "source.xlsx" and one has macros "work.xlsm". I can load the data from "source.xlsx" into "work.xlsm" using Excel's built-in load or using Application.GetOpenFilename. However, I don't want all the data in the source.xlsx. I only want to select specific rows, the criteria for which will be determined at run time.
Thinks of this as a SELECT from a database with parameters. I need to do this to limit the time and processing of the data being processed by "work.xlsx".
Is there a way to do that?

I tried using parameterized query from Excel --> [Data] --> [From Other Sources] but when I did that, it complained about not finding a table (same with ODBC). This is because the source has no table defined, so it makes sense. But I am restricted from touching the source.

So, In short, I need to filter data before exporting it in the target sheet without touching the source file. I want to do this either interactively or via a VBA macro.

Note: I am using Excel 2003.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated. Thx.

Comment: 3000 points and you only tried one thing?

Comment: if you can upgrade your Excel Version (at least 2010), then the free [Microsoft Add-In Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) could help

Comment: @visu-l, this is a good suggestion. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a macro to convert the source file from .xlsx to .csv format and then loaded the csv formatted file using a loop that contained the desired filter during the load.

This approach may not be the best, nevertheless, no other suggestion was offered and this one works!

The other approach is to abandon the idea of pre-filtering and sacrifice the load time delay and perform the filtering and removal of un-wanted rows in the "work.xlsm" file. Performance and memory size are major factors in this case, assuming code complexity is not the issue.